# Scheduled Reminder is sending 2nd reminder AFTER they have already renewed a membership

Tags: civimail, scheduled-reminders

Powered by CiviCRM 4.6.3

I have 3 reminder emails being sent out to a particular membership type after their memberships expire.

The first is sent 0 hour before Membership End Date on August 1, 2015. The people who have filled out the renewal have had their accounts updated, and their memberships now don't end until Membership End Date July 31, 2016.

Here is what is selected for this email: entity: membership, selected the type, no auto renew options are available. When: 0 hours before membership end date. Record activity for automated email is checked. Repeat is not selected.From Name, From Email, Limit or Add Recipients, and Manual Recipients are all blank. Send email is checked.

The second is sent 1 week after membership end date and the third is set for 1 month after membership end date. However, some members who have already renewed from the first email have gotten the 1 week email even though their account shows an end date of membership as July 31, 2016.

Here is what is selected for this email: entity: membership, selected the type, no auto renew options are available. When: **1 weeks after membership end date**. Record activity for automated email is checked. Repeat is not selected.From Name, From Email, Limit or Add Recipients, and Manual Recipients are all blank. Send email is checked.

It seems like with a new membership end date in 2016, they should not have received an email for 1 week after membership end date. I have checked to make sure that they don't have multiple account that they could be emailed to, and they do not. Another membership we have has the exact same selections, and no problems I am aware of have arisen. A third membership type we have has auto renew options. They are Renewal Reminder (non-auto-renew memberships only), Auto-renew Memberships Only, and Reminder for both. These options to not show up for the membership type I am working with.